# Maven1.x: javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl not found

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, struts1

After OS update from Windows 7 to Windows 10, I'm facing following error:
Apache Maven 
intelligent projects ~
v. 1.0.2

> javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl not 
>   at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance(SAXParserFactory.java:93)
>       at org.apache.maven.jelly.JellyUtils.compileScript(JellyUtils.java:202)
>       at org.apache.maven.jelly.JellyUtils.compileScript(JellyUtils.java:180)
>       at org.apache.maven.jelly.JellyUtils.compileScript(JellyUtils.java:146)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginManager.loadScript(PluginManager.java:1109)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginManager.runScript(PluginManager.java:1135)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginManager.initialiseHousingPluginContext(PluginManager.java:770)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginManager.prepAttainGoal(PluginManager.java:725)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginManager.attainGoals(PluginManager.java:656)
>       at org.apache.maven.MavenSession.attainGoals(MavenSession.java:263)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.App.doMain(App.java:488)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.App.main(App.java:1239)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:324)
>       at com.werken.forehead.Forehead.run(Forehead.java:551)
>       at com.werken.forehead.Forehead.main(Forehead.java:581)
>   You have encountered an unknown error running Maven. Please help us to correct 
>   this problem by following these simple steps:
>   - read the Maven FAQ at http://maven.apache.org/faq.html
>   - run the same command again with the '-e' parameter, eg maven -e jar

As my application is using Maven1 and JDK1.4, I'm running eclipse:generate-classpath command.
I also tried to add xerces and xercesImpl jars via maven. Also added these two jars in C:\Dev\Jdks\jdk1.8.0_31\jre\lib\ext directory. Still getting the same error. Can anyone please help? I'll be greatful, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that maven 1 and maven 2 have reached EOL and running it on such a recent OS might be the source of your problem.

Comment: `jdk1.8.0_31` is not JDK 1.4

Comment: I would delete my local maven repository

Comment: Maven 1 is end of life very very very long...and Maven 2 as well..So why are you using Maven 1 ?

Comment: I found the solution :)

Comment: Maven got corrupted so I reintalled and now it's working